# Implicit differentiation (calc 1)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, implicit-differentiation

The problem says find $dy/dx$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. I'm having trouble reaching the answer provided on the last line under "should be".

[image]

Comment: First multiply the equation by $x(x+y)$ to avoid the use of the quotient rule. You'll arrive in $0=x^3+x^2y+2y^2$.

Comment: Follow the advice of @MichaelHoppe .  Differentiate and you'll get $0=3x^2+2xy + x^2y'+4yy'$ which rearranges to $y'=-\frac{3x^2+2xy}{x^2+4y}$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe thanks I did it correctly now! I understood how the multiplying the equation by $x(x+y)$ avoided the quotient rule, but I would never have come up with it. What's the heuristic?

Comment: Well, when I was 14 -- that's *really* long ago -- my math teacher told me: "If you come across some equation involving fractions: multiply it with the common denominator first!"  Just to avoid fractions, if possible.  Believe it or not: I still remember that day ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe This technique is nice, but why is $x(x+y)$ the common denominator rather than $y(x+y)$? I will also try without multiplying by the common denominator, I should still get the same answer or a different one? It may be harder but I just want to have confidence that the math works.

Comment: Ups, you’re right about the common denominator.  But the result is right, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree that the "should-be" answer is correct. Differentiating both sides of the initial equation and solving for $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ gives

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(x+y)\left(1-\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)-(x-y)\left(1+\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)}{(x+y)^2}&=\frac{2xy-x^2\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}}{y^2}\\[1ex]
\frac{2y}{(x+y)^2}-\frac{2x}{(x+y)^2}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}&=\frac{2x}y-\frac{x^2}{y^2}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\\[1ex]
\left(\frac{x^2}{y^2}-\frac{2x}{(x+y)^2}\right)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}&=\frac{2x}y-\frac{2y}{(x+y)^2}\\[1ex]
\frac{x^2(x+y)^2-2xy^2}{y^2(x+y)^2}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}&=\frac{2x(x+y)^2-2y^2}{y(x+y)^2}\\[1ex]
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}&=\frac{2xy(x+y)^2-2y^3}{x^2(x+y)^2-2xy^2}
\end{align*}$$

which is not the same as the suggested solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that due to the implicit relation that holds for $x$ and $y,$ two algebraically different expressions could still represent the same derivative. I haven't checked whether that is what's going on here, however.